# Converting double to float in C# giving wrong values

Tags: c#, double, type-conversion

Question is real simple. I have a double which I want to convert to float.

```
double doubleValue = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565;
float floatValue = (float)doubleValue;
```

Now when I do this. Float value just goes mad. Its value is "**1.110223E-16**" Do I need to do something extra for this flow. Value should be 0 or 0.1 but it is not here. What the problem here?

Comment: you are trying to round off your `Double` value? isn't it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Converting `double` to `float` will definitely be loss of precision . But the value `1.110223E-16` is exponent notation i.e. raised to power -16 that means it is something like `0.0000000000000001110223`.

You should use [Math.Round()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) to round numbers.

Comment: ah, it is the same. There was another problem in my code. I was checking that whether this number is in between two numbers and it was giving false. It was working fine for double. But now when I rechecked this someone changed that range and condition became false.

Answer (score 2):

The float is perfectly fine. It represents the value of the double up to the precision of a float.

`1.110223E-16` is another notation for `0.0000000000000001110223`.

Answer (score 1):

[`Double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx) is *double-precision floating-point number* but [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) is *single-precision floating-point number*.

So normally, you can loss precision when you convert `Double` to `float`. `1.110223E-16` is equal something like `0.0000000000000001110223` as it representation.

If you want to round the nearest number your values, you can use [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx) method.

> Rounds a value to the nearest integer or to the specified number of
>   fractional digits.

Take a look at The [Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0):

A float is capable of representing about 6 *significant figures* with perfect accuracy. That's not the same thing as 6 *decimal places* which is what I think you were assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is giving the right value.

> How about getting rid of exponent after converting to float

```
double doubleValue = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565;
float result = (float)doubleValue;
decimal d = Decimal.Parse(result.ToString(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);
```